# array_push() and in_array() not able to figure it out

Tags: php

I have the following file which contains the next code and i am trying to keep track of some items by adding them to an array.

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$json_output = array();
$json_parcurs = array();
function generate_json_file($depth, &$json_output, $parent_id, &$children = null, $child_nr = null , $percentage = 0,$id_child = null,$type = 0,&$json_parcurs){


[code].....


 for($i=0; $i<$nr_of_children; $i++)
            {
                if (!in_array($firma[$i+1]['vessta_id'],$json_parcurs))
                    // Run recurence function
                    if ($firma[$i+1]['shareholder_id'] != '')
                    {
                        array_push($json_parcurs,$firma[$i+1]['vessta_id']);
                        generate_json_file($depth, $json_output, $table_init[1][0], $json_output['children'], $i,$firma[$i+1]['percentage_held'],$firma[$i+1]['vessta_id'],0,$json_parcurs);
                   }                     
            }

}
generate_json_file(0, $json_output, 0);

echo json_encode($json_output);
```

My problem is that i get a lot of warnings like so :

```
[05-Jan-2013 22:49:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in 
[05-Jan-2013 22:49:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

Comment: `$json_parcurs` doesn't have a value please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using default function arguments in the wrong way. You always have to specify the default.

Try defining your function like this -

```
function generate_json_file(... $type = 0,$json_parcurs = &$json_parcurs){
 ...
}
```

Comment: @sta - I shortened the parameter list for the sake of this answer.. did you just copy and paste it?

Comment: i knew that, but $json_parcurs = &$json_parcurs is a syntax error.

Comment: Perhaps you should actually pass this array to the function. Otherwise you could always use [the dreaded `global` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) to import the array into the functions scope.